# How do I overlay a histogram with a plot of CDF?

Tags: plotting, graphics, histograms, overlay

```
data = Flatten[Import["speedtest1B.csv"]];
distrib = HistogramDistribution[data];
histogram = Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> {Blue}];
Export["speedtest1B.pdf", 
    Overlay[{ 
    Histogram[
        data, 
        ChartStyle -> {Blue},
        ImageSize -> {500,500},
        AxesLabel -> {"start-up time [ms]", "number of samples"}
        ],
    DiscretePlot[
        CDF[distrib, x], 
        {x, 0, Max[data]},
        ImageSize -> {500,500},
        Axes -> False
        ]
        }
    ]
];
```

From the above I get:

[image]

I would like the plots to be properly aligned. Displaying the CDF x-axis on the right side of the plot would be a big plus. Also I don't realy get color-theaming so could someone please explain how to easily change the color od CDF to red.

Comment: Inside `Overlay` should be `{...}`, but you don't even need `Overlay`, use `Show` - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 data = 1000 RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[3, .5], 10^4];
 distrib = HistogramDistribution[data];
 Overlay[{DiscretePlot[CDF[distrib, x], {x, 0, Max[data]},
  ImageSize -> {600, 400}, Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}},
  FrameTicks -> {{None, Range[0.1, 1, .1]}, {None, None}},
  ImagePadding -> {{50, 100}, {15, 25}}],
 Histogram[data, ChartStyle -> Opacity[.5, Blue],
  ImageSize -> {600, 400}, ImagePadding -> {{50, 100}, {15, 25}},
  AxesLabel -> {Style["start-up time [ms]", 12],
     Style["number of samples", 12]}]},
  Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: awesome! thank you! Any idea how to label the axes? Simple AxesLabel doesnt really work.

Comment: @JohnnyM, please see the update. (You need to adjust the values for the `ImagePadding` option to _see_ the axes labels.)

Comment: thanks! maybe you could help with my other question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18733/how-to-rebuild-original-data-from-a-histogram I think it is quite basic.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a very old question, but perhaps an updated answer might make this easier for seekers such as myself who have a need to superimpose a CDF over a histogram.  The following function uses SmoothedHistogram with the “PDF” option.

```
data=1000RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[3,0.5], 10^3];

histoCDF[data_,smHist_:True]:=Overlay[{
   Histogram[data,Automatic, PlotRange->Full, ImageSize -> {600, 400}, 
      ChartStyle->Lighter[Blue,0.8], 
      ImagePadding -> {{50, 100}, {15, 25}}, 
      BaseStyle->Directive[Black,14],
      Frame->{{True,False},{True, False}}, 
      FrameStyle->Directive[Black,14],
      FrameLabel->{{"Number of Samples",None},
         {"Start-up Time (min)", None}}],

   SmoothHistogram[data,Automatic,"CDF",
      ImageSize -> {600, 400}, 
      FrameStyle->Directive[Black,14],
      PlotStyle->Darker[Red,0.3],
      PlotRange->Full, 
      FrameTicks->{{None,Range[0.0,1.0,0.2]},
         {None,None}},
      FrameLabel->{{None, "Cumulative Probability"}
          ,{None,None}},
      Frame->{{False,True},{False,False}}, 
      Axes->None, ImagePadding -> {{50, 100}, {15, 25}}],

   If[smHist,
      SmoothHistogram[data,Automatic, 
      PlotRange->Full,PlotStyle->Blue,
      ImageSize -> {600, 400}, Axes->None,
      ImagePadding -> {{50, 100}, {15, 25}}],""]
}, Alignment->{Top,Center}]
```

Overlaying plots is now seamless, with no alignment issues.  Smoothed histogram is included for comparison.

[image: Overlay histogram with CDF]

N.B. You need to use Automatic for bin specification, otherwise strange things happen with the smoothed histogram and the CDF.

Comment: It's a very good idea to use `SmoothHistogram` but because that is a 21st century replacement for a histogram, is there a great need to show both?  (Maybe if one doesn't trust smooth histograms.  But if the underlying distribution is smooth, why would anyone want to see a blocky histogram?)  Also, the alignment is off in your display.  The smooth histogram should be right on top of the histogram.  Using `Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], SmoothHistogram[data]]` is simpler and there is no misalignment.