# How to get list of duplicates when using DeleteDuplicates?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

This might be easy, but can't find a way to use `DeleteDuplicates` to get also list of the actual duplicates.

Example:

```
lstA = {1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8};
r = DeleteDuplicates[lstA]
(* {1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8} *)
```

I also wanted to get list of the actual duplicates, which are `{4,8}` in this example.
It would have been nice if `DeleteDuplicates` would also return those, but there is no option there for that. I do not know what many Mathematica functions do not return back more useful information when called. Many seem to return one piece of information only, and one has to call another function to get another piece of information.

For example, here `DeleteDuplicates` could had an API like this

```
{r,d}=DeleteDuplicates[lst]
```

and `r` will contain the list after duplicates are moved, but `d` would contain the actual list of duplicates. To make it even more useful, it can be

```
{r,d,p}=DeleteDuplicates[lst]
```

Where `p` will be the positions of the duplicates in the original list. Matlab seems to do it this way. Many functions there can return more than one piece of information at a time. This might be due to WL being functional programming language, and designed for cascading function calls, where each function only does one thing at a time. I am not sure now.

[DeleteDuplicates.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html)

Comment: You want to get list of the duplicates in general, or such list with `DeleteDuplicates` usage?

Comment: @Kuba actually I found couple of places where they talk about finding positions of duplicates in lists but did not yet understand the code. I was hoping that DeleteDuplicate can do it. But if you know of an easy way to get list of duplicates (without using DeleteDuplicates) that will work also. Thanks.

Comment: What's with the [tag:wolfram-language] tag? Is it necessary? In principle, this tag could be applied to every question...

Comment: @IstvánZachar `What's with the wolfram-language tag?` I was just trying to do my part to make the new name popular :) But will remove this tag now, no problem.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded harsh, but I really don't share SW's zeal about all the "new" products. And as I gathered it, Wolfram Language is really not much more than (the core of) _Mathematica_, so I guess we don't want to go down the slope where we end up retagging all questions here and/or on SO, or even renaming _Mathematica_.SE to Wolfram.SE. Personally I find it bad style to name a product and a language after yourself.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I agree. This tag is now banned at the system level and can no longer be used. Please also be on the lookout for variations of "wolfram-language".

Comment: I just have noticed an upvote on [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/316/169) answer and guessed that was related to this question. I think the fact that a function in matlab gets the information about how many arguments its caller expects from it is very unique and somewhat unusual (are there other languages having this?). My mentioned answer did mimic that behavior by examining the stack, but it's more a hack than a solution. Without that feature, you can of course not expect a function to return different things depending on how many return values the caller expects...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Perhaps one of the simplest ways is to use `Tally`:

```
p = {1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8};

Cases[Tally @ p, {x_, n_ /; n > 1} :> x]
```

> ```
> {4, 8}
> ```

A somewhat faster formulation:

```
Pick[#, Unitize[#2 - 1], 1] & @@ Transpose[Tally @ p]
```

Taking the optimization to a rather excessive degree:

```
#[[SparseArray[#2, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]]] & @@ Transpose[Tally @ p]
```

---

Though not as fast as the `SparseArray` optimized form of `Tally`, an alternative is to use `Split` after sorting.  This is reasonably clean and fast:

```
Flatten[Split @ Sort @ p, {2}][[2]]
```

> ```
> {4, 8}
> ```

For Integer data this method is twice as fast as any other listed here:

```
With[{s = Sort @ p},
 DeleteDuplicates @ 
   s[[ SparseArray[Unitize @ Differences @ s, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"] ]]
]
```

---

### Timings

```
p = RandomInteger[1*^8, 1*^6];

Cases[Tally @ p, {x_, n_ /; n > 1} :> x] // Timing // First

Pick[#, Unitize[#2 - 1], 1] & @@ Transpose[Tally @ p] // Timing // First

#[[SparseArray[#2, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]]] & @@ Transpose[Tally @ p] //
  Timing // First

Flatten[Split @ Sort @ p, {2}][[2]] // Timing // First

With[{s = Sort @ p},
 DeleteDuplicates @ 
   s[[ SparseArray[Unitize @ Differences @ s, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"] ]]
] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.827
>
> 0.343
>
> 0.265
>
> 0.343
>
> 0.11
> ```

Comment: @Nasser & Mr.Wizard I like this answer but it is not the final answer to the question. You havn't asked about list of duplicates but about that and standard result from `DD` at once. I don't mean that something terrible is going on here but it is strange that the accepted answer do not fit the question, isn't it? :)

Comment: I agree with @Kuba, as if one omits the request for the advanced API the question becomes quite trivial, perhaps even would have been closed down due to the fact that the answer is easy to find in the documentation. Nevertheless, I (and others no doubt) find the Q inspiring, as it forced me to explore `Reap` in more depths.

Comment: Kuba and @István I didn't see the point in packaging this into a function that returns "{r, d, p}".  Methods for the positions of duplicates can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21341/121).  If you are focusing on the "API" I believe that has been asked before, perhaps by rm -rf.  I'll try to find it.

Comment: Found it: [Constructing functions with variable number of output arguments](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/314/121)

Comment: The difference is that the result in form `{r, d, p}` is more challenging in terms of efficiency. For example in my `myClone` positions are gathered with additional scanning, where one could get them earlier if knows how.

Answer (score 16):

If you have to use `DeleteDuplicates` you can use `Sow`/`Reap`:

```
{#, Pick @@ Transpose[GatherBy[#2[[1]]][[;; , 1]]]} & @@ Reap[
   DeleteDuplicates[lstA, (Sow[{#1, SameQ[##]}]; SameQ[##]) &]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8}, {4, 8}}
> ```

---

Here's more general and faster approach:

```
myClone[list_, test_: Identity] := Composition[
       {#[[1]], #[[2]], Position[list, #] & /@ #[[2]]} &,
       {#[[;; , 1]], DeleteCases[#, {_}][[;; , 1]]} &,
       GatherBy[#, test] &
       ][list]

lstA = RandomInteger[10, 10]
myClone[lstA]
```

> ```
> {5, 6, 3, 5, 10, 10, 8, 7, 0, 10}
>
> {{5, 6, 3, 10, 8, 7, 0}, {5, 10}, {{{1}, {4}}, {{5}, {6}, {10}}}}
> ```

Comment: Nice. Now would it not be good if Mathematica DeleteDuplicate returned both of these lists as well? (if user wanted)

Comment: @Nasser I don't know, I think it might be the case where there is no "most useful output" so they left it in quite raw form :)

Answer (score 8):

Similar to Kuba's solution, but more compact, using `Reap`'s third argument to remove duplicates *from the duplicates*:

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1};

Reap[DeleteDuplicates[x, If[SameQ[##], Sow@#1; True, False] &], _, Union@#2 &]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {{1, 4, 5}}}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

I am posting a second answer because this is a different method unrelated to the first.
I wondered how I might approach this if `Tally` did not exist.  I came up with using `Ordering` on a reverse-sorted list as a way to look for duplicates.  It seems to work, and I think it's fairly interesting. By nature it sorts the list of duplicates rather than giving them in order of appearance as `Tally` does.

```
duplicates[p_] :=
  With[{sp = Sort @ p}, sp[[
     "AdjacencyLists" //
       SparseArray[Unitize[1 - Differences @ Ordering @ Reverse @ sp], Automatic, 1]
    ]]
  ] // DeleteDuplicates

duplicates[{1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8}]
```

> ```
> {4, 8}
> ```

It is competitively fast compared to my first answer:

```
p = RandomInteger[8*^6, 2*^6];

Cases[Tally@p, {x_, n_ /; n > 1} :> x] // Length // Timing

Pick[#, Unitize[#2 - 1], 1] & @@ Transpose[Tally@p] // Length // Timing

#[[SparseArray[#2, Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]]] & @@ Transpose[Tally@p] // 
  Length // Timing

duplicates[p] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.70041, 212277}
>
> {0.592804, 212277}
>
> {0.608404, 212277}
>
> {0.358802, 212277}
> ```

On lists with extreme duplication it is a bit slower:

```
p = RandomInteger[1*^6, 5*^6];

(* same timing code as before *)
```

> ```
> {1.57561, 959792}
>
> {0.904806, 959792}
>
> {0.904806, 959792}
>
> {0.982806, 959792}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

*Important: Union with one argument does exactly what I describe below. I don't know how I missed that for so long. Anyway I suppose it is still nice to be able to return a list of the positions of the duplicates. And there may be other cases where you know a result is sorted I guess.*

**Original answer**

I have long been a bit frustrated about the fact that there is neither an option for `Sort` that deletes duplicates, nor an `option` for `DeleteDuplicates` that makes it assume its input is sorted. `DeleteDuplicates` probably first sorts its argument, but still even determining that a list is sorted is unnecessary overhead. I saw that in your question the numbers were sorted, so I have focussed on this case.

In my opinion, your questions and my own made for a good case to make a library with LibraryLink. Here is the code. It is a bit long, especially because similar code is used over and over.

```c
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

static MTensor positions;
// static MTensor frequencies;

/* Return the version of Library Link */
DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion( ) {
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

/* Initialize Library */
DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

/* Uninitialize Library */
DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return;
}

//DD is for delete duplicates
DLLEXPORT int sortedDD_T_T(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    MTensor input; //not redundant as we access this two times, once for data and once for dimension
    MTensor result;

    int err = LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;

    mint *inputDataPtr;
    mint *resultDataPtr;

    mint inputDataLen;

    input = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);

    inputDataPtr = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(input);

    inputDataLen = * libData->MTensor_getDimensions(input);

    mint array[inputDataLen];
    mint *arrayPtr;
    arrayPtr = array;

//below is basically the first (0th) iteration
    mint max = *inputDataPtr;
    inputDataPtr++;
    *arrayPtr = max;
    arrayPtr++;

    mint val;
    mint resultDataLenCounter = 1;
    mint iiii;

    for(iiii = 1; iiii < inputDataLen; iiii++)
    {
        val = *inputDataPtr;
        inputDataPtr++;
        if( val != max)
        {
            *arrayPtr = val;
            arrayPtr++;
            resultDataLenCounter++;
            max = val;
        }
    }

    err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, &resultDataLenCounter, &result);
    if(err) goto error_label;

    resultDataPtr = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(result);

    arrayPtr = array;

    for(iiii = 0; iiii < resultDataLenCounter; iiii++){
        *(resultDataPtr++) = * (arrayPtr++);
    }

    libData->MTensor_disown(input);

    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, result);
    return err;

    error_label:
    libData->MTensor_disown(input);

    if(!err) err = 1;
    return err; 

}


//WP is for with positions

DLLEXPORT int sortedDDWP_T_T(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    MTensor input; //not redundant as we access this two times, once for data and once for dimension
    MTensor result;

    int err = LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;

    mint *inputDataPtr;
    mint *resultDataPtr;
    mint *posDataPtr;

    mint inputDataLen;

    input = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);

    inputDataPtr = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(input);

    inputDataLen = * libData->MTensor_getDimensions(input);

    mint uqArray[inputDataLen];
    mint *uqArrayPtr;
    uqArrayPtr = uqArray;

    mint posArray[inputDataLen];
    mint *posArrayPtr;
    posArrayPtr = posArray;

    mint posLen;


//below is basically the first (0th) iteration
    mint max = *inputDataPtr;
    inputDataPtr++;
    *uqArrayPtr = max;
    uqArrayPtr++;

    mint val;
    mint resultDataLenCounter = 1;
    mint iiii;

    for(iiii = 1; iiii < inputDataLen; iiii++)
    {
        val = *inputDataPtr;
        inputDataPtr++;
        if( val != max)
        {
            *uqArrayPtr = val;
            uqArrayPtr++;
            resultDataLenCounter++;
            max = val;
        } 
        else 
        {
            *posArrayPtr = iiii;
            posArrayPtr++;
        }
    }

    posLen = inputDataLen - resultDataLenCounter;

    err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, &resultDataLenCounter, &result);
    if(err) goto error_label;

    err = libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, &posLen, &positions);
    if(err) goto error_label;

    resultDataPtr = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(result);
    posDataPtr = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(positions);

    uqArrayPtr = uqArray;
    posArrayPtr = posArray;

    for(iiii = 0; iiii < resultDataLenCounter; iiii++){
        *(resultDataPtr++) = * (uqArrayPtr++);
    }

    for(iiii = 0; iiii < posLen; iiii++){
        *(posDataPtr++) = *(posArrayPtr++);
    }

    libData->MTensor_disown(input);

    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, result);
    return err;

    error_label:
    libData->MTensor_disown(input);

    if(!err) err = 1;
    return err; 

}

DLLEXPORT int getPositions(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {

    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, positions);
    // libData->MTensor_disown(positions);
    return 0;
}
```

for the steps ("instructions") for compiling and linking the code, please see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37961/4330).

```
(* libraryName = "libraryName"; *) (*this is the last line from the "instructions"*)
```

The following code loads the functions.

`SortedDD` is the function that simply deletes duplicates from a sorted list.

```
sortedDD = 
 LibraryFunctionLoad[libraryName, 
  "sortedDD_T_T", {{Integer, 1, "Shared"}}, {Integer, 1}]
```

`sortedDDWP` is the function that makes a list with duplicates deleted, as well of a list of positions of the duplicates.

```
sortedDDWP = 
 LibraryFunctionLoad[libraryName, 
  "sortedDDWP_T_T", {{Integer, 1, "Shared"}}, {Integer, 1}]
```

As we can only return one argument in LibraryLink, we have to work around this and get the positions with another function call. This is what `getPos` does.

```
getPos = LibraryFunctionLoad[libraryName, 
  "getPositions", {}, {Integer, 1}]
```

**Performance**

WARNING: One big problem with my code is that it crashes the kernel for large input. This is because of a stackoverflow that I intend to fix.

Now let's create some random numbers. I chose to generate a `BinomialProcess`, i.e., a process that increases by with probably 1/2 and otherwise stays the same. So a sequence could be `normal = {0,1,1,1,2,2}` and we expect about 50% duplicates.

```
nnnn = 1002000;
randomize :=
 Block[{rands},
  rands = RandomInteger[1, nnnn];
  normal = Accumulate[rands]
  ];
```

now let's compare with `DeleteDuplicates`

```
sortedDD@normal // Timing // First
DeleteDuplicates@normal // Timing // First
```

> 0.008401 
>   0.018445

That is quite nice :). Now let's see what happens if we also generate the positions list

```
kkkk = 522000;
(
   mOut =
     {
      sortedDDWP[normal[[;; kkkk]]],
      getPos[]
      };
   ) // Timing // First
```

> 0.006506

and we have

```
mOut[[1]] == Delete[normal[[;; kkkk]], List /@ mOut[[2]]]
```

> True

**Notes about the C Code**

If you read the C Code, you will that I make an array, only to copy the contents of that array into another array. Unfortunately I think there is no good way around this.

Comment: Oh by the way to get the actual duplicates just do `Part[normal[[;;kkkk]], mOut[[2]]]`

Comment: I don't think `DeleteDuplicates` sorts its argument first: `DeleteDuplicates[{5, 4, 3, 4, 1}, (Print[{##}]; SameQ[##]) &]` clearly reports otherwise.

Comment: @IstvánZachar it's possible that the behavior is different for a user specified test. I could not find a claim of this for DeleteDuplicates, but [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node290.html) Leonid claims the behavior for `Union` changes.

Comment: You are right Jacob, similar tests for `DeleteDuplicates` indicate similar increase in time when `SameQ[##]&` is used instead of `SameQ`. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @IstvánZachar :) no problem! Good that you tested it out. However do not underestimate the impact on timing of that `SameQ[##]&` requires the tests to be evaluated by Mathematica, whereas otherwise everything can be done "in C". I wish my code worked on larger data so we could do more comparisons. The most convincing thing for me is that calling `DeleteDuplicates` on increasingly large lists seems to give a (quasi-)linear increase in timing.

Comment: Todo: Hah I see I made a harmless mistake. I give the positions of the elements before duplicate elements, instead of the positions of duplicate elements. However the numbers at these positions are always the same as the duplicates themselves. Also you will that -> you will see that

Comment: Todo: It turned out the program crashed because of a stack overflow. It appears the large arrays were allocated on the stack, rather than the heap. We can use malloc to overcome this problem. Furthermore it seems there is no way to hack together a "setIntegerData". MTensor is a typedef for a pointer to a struct. This struct contains a pointer, which is supposedly the pointer to the (integer)data. However, simply setting this pointer, as well as setting length of the array which is also a property of this struct, has no effect.

Answer (score 6):

This uses a function which redefines itself, and `MapIndexed` to get the position data:

```
deldup[z_] := Module[{f},
  f[x_, _] := (f[x, q_] := (Sow[q, x]; Unevaluated@Sequence[]); x);
  Reap[MapIndexed[f, z], _, Rule]]

deldup[{1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2}]
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2 -> {{5}, {7}}, 3 -> {{6}}}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Some variants with `Reap/Sow` or `Tally`:

```
fun1[u_] := {#[[1]], Pick[#[[1]], (# > 1) & /@ #[[2]]]} &@
  Transpose[Reap[Sow[1, #] & /@ u, _, {#1, Total@#2} &][[2]]]
```

or

```
fun2[u_] := {#[[1]], Pick[#[[1]], (# > 1) & /@ #[[2]]]} &@
  Transpose@Tally[u]
```

Comment: I am giving a +1 for using `Transpose@Tally[u]` but see my answer for a faster method to do the second part.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you for instruction...am always glad to improve...Unitize very nice

Answer (score 5):

Another way to get the dupe-free list and the list of duplicates:

```
With[{grouped = Gather[lstA, SameQ], pattern = {x_, __} :> x},
    {Flatten@Replace[grouped, pattern, 1], Cases[grouped, pattern]}
]
(* {{1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8}, {4, 8}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

`delinit[v_List] := Module[{f}, f[x_] := (f[x] = x; Unevaluated[]); f/@v]` deletes the initial instance of every term in `v`. All instances after the first are kept, in the order in which they come. This is the logical complement of `DeleteDuplicates`.

EDIT - `deli` does the same thing, but faster.

```
deli[v_List] := Delete[v,Transpose@List@Part[Range[Length@v][[#]],
     Most@FoldList[Plus,1,Length/@Split@v[[#]]]]]& @ Ordering@v
```

Comment: Nice! I do not know how it works, but it does :) btw, the FE on V 9.01  does not like `Unevaluated[]` it puts little red marker between the `[]` but it still worked.

Comment: If you know that `v` contains no sublists then you could change `Unevaluated[]` to `{}` and do `Flatten[f/@v]`. Or change `Unevaluated[]` to `Hold@Sequence[]` and do `ReleaseHold[f/@v]`, which should work no matter what is in `v`.

Comment: @Nasser - Sorry, I forgot about what's probably the easiest fix -- just change `Unevaluated[]` to Mr.Wizard's "vanishing function", `##&[]`.

Comment: @Nasser you can change the `SyntaxInformation` of `Unevaluated` if you like to use the zero or multiple argument form; AFAICT it is perfectly usable that way.  Ray, thanks for the mention regarding `##&[]` -- it is my favorite method.

Answer (score 4):

For fun of it: `list = {1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8};`

```
DeleteDuplicates@Cases[Subsets[list, {2}], {a_, a_}][[;; , 1]]
```

> `{4, 8}`

Comment: Not efficient, but fun indeed. +1 :-)  Nice use of named patterns, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

```
CustomDeleteDuplicates[lst_List] := 
 Module[{lstA = lst}, {lstA //. {s___, a_, a_, g___} -> {s, a, g}, 
   Complement[lstA, lstA //. {s___, a_, a_, g___} -> {s, 0, g}]}]
```

> {{1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8}, {4, 8}}

**EDIT:**
As pointed out I have updated code that is working with all use cases. I have used patterns to find out duplicates to filter out as many repetitions as can be made. It will filter out all even pairs and last remaining in case of odd count will be dealt with next function acting on it.

```
CustomDeleteDuplicates[li_List] := 
 Block[{l = li}, {Flatten[l] //. {s___, a_, k___, a_, g___} -> {s, a, k, g}, 
   Complement[l,Pick[(l //. {s___, a_, k___, a_, g___} -> {s, k, g}), 
     Count[l, #] & /@ (l //. {s___, a_, k___, a_, g___} -> {s, k, g}),  1]]}]
```

{13, 12, 2, 15, 2, 6, 7, 2, 4, 7, 12, 15, 6, 15, 12, 14, 15, 10, 14,
  1}

```
Gather[l]
```

> {{13}, {12, 12, 12}, {2, 2, 2}, {15, 15, 15, 15}, {6, 6}, {7, 
>     7}, {4}, {14, 14}, {10}, {1}}

CustomDeleteCases[l]

> {{13, 12, 2, 15, 6, 7, 4, 14, 10, 1}, {2, 6, 7, 12, 14, 15}}

And an even simpler solution with `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
list = {13, 12, 2, 15, 2, 6, 7, 2, 4, 7, 12, 15, 6, 15, 12, 14, 15, 10, 14, 1};
{list, {}} //. {{a___, b_, c___, b_, d___}, {du___}} :> {{a, b, c, d}, Union@{du, b}}
```

> ```
>  {{13, 12, 2, 15, 6, 7, 4, 14, 10, 1}, {2, 6, 7, 12, 14, 15}}
> ```

Comment: This only works if the duplicates are next to each other, and there are no more than 2 of each. You should also use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) instead of `Rule` (`->`) if using named patterns to avoid interference with any predifined `s`, `a` or `g`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar : Actually I knew my mistake, I have updated it now, I think its working fine now. I always had some doubt about `->` vs ':>`, now I think am more clear on reading your comment. Thanks :)

Comment: I still find it pretty convoluted :) You scan through the lists so many times! Also, the `Block is unnecessary, you could work on `li` directly; `Complement` and `Pick` can be replaced by `Union`; you do the `//.` three times, though one would be enough. I could not resist and edited in a simpler solution, because I find your `ReplaceRepeated` approach quite interesting! Please feel free to revert my edit if you think so!

Comment: @IstvánZachar I am always open to anyone editing my answer to make it better so, thanks :) . I tend to use 'Block' to prevent any outside variable intervention, nothing else.

Comment: I see your intention, though `li` in `f[li_]:=(...)` is as much local and protected from the outside as `l` in `f[li_]:=Block[{l=li}, (...)]`. `Block` however does not make by itself `s`, `k`, `g` locals.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I wasn't aware of this, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

With `Sow/Reap` and `Pick`

```
listp = {1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8};
```

(i) List duplicate values

```
Reap[Sow[1,listp],_,Pick[#1,Unitize[Length@#2-1],1]&][[2]]
```

> {4, 8}

(ii) Delete all duplicates (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215552/106))

```
Reap[Sow[1,listp],_,Pick[#1,#2,{1}]&][[2]]
```

> {1, 2, 6, 7}

(iii) Delete duplicates (from [Reap Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html), unsorted Union)

```
Reap[Sow[1,listp],_,#1&][[2]]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8};
```

**List duplicate values**

```
dups = SequenceCases[list, {a_, a_} :> a]
```

{4, 8}

**Delete all duplicates**

```
DeleteElements[list, dups]
```

{1, 2, 6, 7}

```
WolframLanguageData[#, {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}] & /@ {"SequenceCases", "DeleteElements"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably not working in every case:

```
Select[Partition[Sort[lstA], 2, 1, 1], #[[1]] == #[[2]] &][[All, 1]]

(* {4, 8} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SubsetCases` and `Cases`:

```
list = {4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8};

Cases[SubsetCases[list, {s_ ..}], x_ /; Length[x] > 1 :> First@x]

(*{4, 8}*)
```

Or using `GroupBy` and `Repeated`:

```
g = GroupBy[list, Repeated];

Keys@Select[KeyMap[Times @@ List @@ # &, g], Length@# > 1 &]

(*{4, 8}*)
```

Comment: Also: `In[2215]:= Union[ResourceFunction["Duplicates"][list]]

Out[2215]= {4, 8}`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that it exists as a resource function, @DanielLichtblau!